# How to add "Note" section to WooCommerce Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a "Notes" section to each product for internal use. I don't want it visible to the public - just a place for each Admin to write and update information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no dedicated section for this however, you can add your own customer meta field which does the same thing here http://cld.wthms.co/1eS4f

Comment: Or you could create your own meta box with [`add_meta_box()`[http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box].

Answer (score 6):

I created a plugin that might have what you are looking for
https://wordpress.org/plugins/products-admin-notes-simple/

This plugin simply adds a text field in the general area for a product description. The box is only visable to admins.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I've added some content

Comment: Thank you v much :)